# Trouble updating a blog in my CRUD application using Axios - getting 404 error

Tags: reactjs, node.js, axios, crud, mern

I'm building a CRUD application for my blog, and I'm facing an issue specifically with updating a blog entry. I've successfully implemented the functionality for creating blogs and retrieving a single blog by its ID. However, when I try to update a blog, I keep getting a 404 error indicating "not found".

Here's my handleFormSubmit function:

```
const handleFormSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      const response = await axios.put(
        `http://localhost:4000/api/blog/${id}`,
        blog
      );
      if (response.status === 200) {
        alert("Blog updated successfully!");
      } else {
        alert("Something went wrong");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      alert("Internal Server Error");
    }
};
```

And here are my backend routes:

```
import express from "express";
import {
  getAllBlogs,
  getBlogById,
  createBlog,
  updateBlog,
  deleteBlog,
} from "../controllers/blogController.js";

const router = express.Router();

router.post("/", createBlog); // Create a new blog
router.get("/", getAllBlogs); // Get all blogs
router.get("/:id", getBlogById); // Get a single blog by ID
router.put("/:id", updateBlog); // Update a blog by ID
router.delete("/:id", deleteBlog); // Delete a blog by ID

export default router;
```

Initially, I was using the Fetch API and then switched to Axios, but the problem persists. Any ideas on how I can troubleshoot and fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

In your `handleFormSubmit()` function, you are calling `http://localhost:4000/api/blog/${id}` but you do not have a PUT route defined matching `/api/blog/:id`.  So the call you are actually wanting to make would be

```js
axios.put(`http://localhost:4000/${id}`, blog)
```

or update the already defined route to match `/api/blog/:id` or create a new route; whichever better suits your needs.

Comment: but the thing is, in my server.js, im indeed using the route /api/blog/${id} like this, server.use("/api/blog", blogRoutes);

Comment: You should probably update your post with all relevant parts of the problem then.  But based on the information you originally gave, my answer above will resolve the problem.